# Remainder in this case using modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How do you find the remainder when $870^{479}$ is divided by 65?
My approach:

$870\equiv 25\pmod {65}$

=>$174^{479}\equiv 5^{479}\pmod {13}$

=>$174^{479}\equiv 25^{234.5}\pmod {13}$

I am stuck here. Please help.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952810/finding-the-last-two-digits-of-5312442 OR  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844558/how-to-find-last-two-digits-of-22016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $\  ca\bmod cn\,=\, c\,(a\bmod n)\ $ as [we explained here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242), $ $ hence

$\ \, \begin{align} 870^{\large 479}\!\bmod 65\, &=\, 5\,(\color{#0a0}{174}\cdot \color{#c00}{870}^{\large 478}\bmod 13)\\  
&=\,  5\,(\ \color{#0a0}5\cdot (\color{#c00}{\bf -1})^{\large 478}\!\bmod 13)\\
&=\,  5\,(\,\color{#0a0}5\,)
\end{align}\ \ \ $  by $\ \ \ \begin{align}  \color{#0a0}{174}\,&\equiv\,\ \color{#0a0} 5\pmod{13}\\ \color{#c00}{870}\,&\equiv \color{#c00}{\bf -1}\!\!\!\pmod{13}\\ \phantom{.}\end{align}$

Answer (score 2):

$65=13\times5$

$870^{479}\equiv0 \pmod{5}$

$\color{red}{87}0^{479}\equiv\color{red}{9}0^{479}\equiv(-1)^{479}\equiv-1\pmod{13}$

So $x=870^{479}=-1+13k\equiv0 \pmod 5 \rightarrow k\equiv\frac{1}{13}\equiv\frac 13\equiv\frac63\equiv2 \pmod 5$

and therefore, $x=-1+13\times(2+5k')\equiv-1+26\equiv25 \pmod {65}$

Comment: I could not understand the second and third step.

Comment: @MrAP He is applying CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem. I posted an answer that avoids that.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $870^1\equiv870^3\pmod{65}$