# Multiple mod powers $(3^{4^{101}} \pmod{24})$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> $(3^{4^{101}} \pmod{24})$

I'm very inclined to get $4^{101} \pmod{24}$.

But if I have $a \equiv b \pmod{c}$ then is it necessarily true that $f^a \equiv f^b \pmod{c}$?
 Which is arguably what I was planning to do.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952810/finding-the-last-two-digits-of-5312442

Answer (score 1):

One can easily verify the following congruence
$$3^3=3\pmod{24},$$
so we have
$$3^4=3^2\pmod{24}.$$
Next we can obtain recursively the desired result:
$$
\begin{split}
(3^4)^4 &= (3^2)^4=(3^4)^2=3^2\pmod{24}\\
3^{4^3} &= (3^2)^4=3^2\pmod{24}\\
&\dots\\
3^{4^{101}}&=(3^2)^4=3^2=9\pmod{24}.
\end{split}
$$