# Find the remainder when ${{33}^{34}}^{35}$ is divided by 7.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

First of all i have created a sequence of remainder of an expression just like below

1. $33^{1}$             33% 7 =5(remainder)
2. $33^{2}$             5*33% 7 =5*5%7=25%7=4(remainder)
3. $33^{3} $            4*33% 7 =4*5%7=20%7=6(remainder)
4. $33^{4}$            6*33% 7 =6*5%7=30%7=2(remainder)
5. $33^{5} $           2*33% 7 =2*5%7=10%7=3(remainder)
6. $33^{6} $            3*33% 7 =3*5%7=15%7=1(remainder)

Then I turned an expression 
${{33}^{34}}^{35}$

into ${33}^{{34}*{35}}$  which is ${33}^{1190}$ .

${33}^{1190}$ $\div$ `7` = ${{33}^{6}}^{198}$ $*$ `33` $*$ `33` $\div$`7` =`1`$*$ 5$*$  `5`$\div$`7`=`25`$\div$7=`4`(remainder).

indeed the remainder would be `4` but answer for the same question in the book is `2`.

so clarify this if i m correct or wrong.

Comment: See [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228/11619) for many techniques. You do need to use them iteratively to work with the iterated power.

Comment: And $33^{34^{35}}\neq 33^{34\cdot35}$. We do have
$$(33^{34})^{35}=33^{34\cdot35},$$ but the question was about the iterated power
$$33^{34^{35}}=33^{399725722782532944388077717044552088857010024925364224}.$$ That large exponent is $34^{35}$.

Comment: Did you mean $(33^{34})^{35}$ or $33^{({34}^{35})}$?

Comment: For a technique of  finding the remainder of an iterated power, see Lab's answer below. The same technique has been used on many previous posts, so it may be a duplicate (which is why I refrain from upvoting). For a recent example, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2011702/11619).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a general algorithm/technique to find the last digit of a nested exponential?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2713356/whats-a-general-algorithm-technique-to-find-the-last-digit-of-a-nested-exponent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$33\equiv-2\pmod7$$

As $34^{35}$ is even, $$33^{34^{35}}\equiv(-2)^{34^{35}}\equiv2^{34^{35}}\pmod7$$

Now $2^3\equiv1\pmod7,34\equiv1\pmod3,34^{35}\equiv1^{35}\equiv1$

$$\implies2^{34^{35}}\equiv2^1\pmod7$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint. You are dividing the exponent by $7$ not the base!

Note that ${33^6}\equiv (-2)^6=64\equiv 1\pmod{7}$.

What is the remainder of the exponent $34^{35}$ divided by 6?

What may we conclude?

P.S. Note that $33^{({34}^{35})}\equiv 2\pmod{7}$, but $(33^{34})^{35}\equiv 4\pmod{7}$. They are not the same number...