# Find the remainder when ${{50^{51}}^{52}}$ is divided by 11.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

First of all i have created a sequence of remainder of an expression just like below

1. $50^{1}$             50% 11 =6(remainder)
2. $50^{2}$             6*50% 11 =6*6%11=36%11=3(remainder)
3. $50^{3} $            3*50%11 =3*6%11=20%11=7(remainder)
4. $50^{4}$            7*50% 11 =7*6%11=42%11=9(remainder)
5. $50^{5} $           9*50% 11 =9*6%11=54%11=10(remainder)
6. $50^{6} $            10*50% 11=10*6%11=60%11=5(remainder)
7. $50^{7} $            5*50% 11=5*6%11=30%11=8(remainder)
8. $50^{8} $            8*50% 11=8*6%11=48%11=4(remainder)
9. $50^{9} $            4*50% 11=4*6%11=24%11=2(remainder)
10. $50^{10} $            2*50% 11=2*6%11=12%11=1(remainder)

Then I turned an expression

into ${{50^{51}}^{52}}$ which is ${50}^{2652}$

${50}^{2652}$ $\div$ `11` = ${{50}^{10}}^{265}$ $*$ `50` $*$ `50` $\div$`11` =`1`$*$ 6$*$  `6`$\div$`11`=`36`$\div$11=`3`(remainder).

indeed the remainder would be `3` but answer for the same question in the book is `6`.

so clarify this if i m correct or wrong.

Comment: You've already asked [a similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2016596/131263) once, and already made the mistake of assuming $a^{(b^{c})}=(a^b)^c$ once. Now, you have not responded to any of the comments and answers there, telling you about this, so the real question is - do you even bother to read the answers to your questions???

Comment: And strangely enough, you've opened a different account with the exact same username, specifically for this question. I must say that you're kind of (ab)using this website in very bad/poor manner (for your own good, as well as for the good of those who spend their efforts trying to assist you).

Comment: Exactly,@barakmanos I respect your comment .one final thing i wanna know how to treat this kind of exponent  ${{50^{51}}^{52}}$.

Comment: No way sir, i am sorry for the inconveniece but this question really sucks me. @barakmanos

Comment: Also asked at http://mathoverflow.net/q/254830/12357 where it was closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), since $\gcd(11,50)=1$, we get $$50^{51^{52}}\equiv 50^{51^{52}\pmod {10}}\pmod{11}$$

$$\equiv 50^{1^{52}}\equiv 50^{1}\equiv 50\equiv 6\pmod{11}$$

Answer (score 0):

$51^{52}\equiv_{10} 1^{52}\equiv_{10} 1$ or $51^{52}=10k+1$ for some $k$.

Therefore,
$$50^{51^{52}}=50^{10k+1}=50*(50^{10})^k.$$
By Fermat's theorem: $a^{p-1}\equiv_{p} 1$ for $a$ and prime $p$.

Set $a=50$ and $p=11$ in order to get: $50^{10}\equiv_{11} 1$.

Therefore, $(50^{10})^k\equiv_{11} 1$ and finally

$$50^{51^{52}}=50^{10k+1}\equiv_{11} 50\equiv_{11} 6.$$